# Android | setAlartm every day at the same hour | not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager

In my Android app, I would to launch a command each day at 3 a.m. and I use `AlarmManager` and `setRepeating`. When the app start, I do this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcast.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

And this is **MyBroadcast**:

```
public class MyBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("ALARM","Alarm worked.");
    }
}
```

Buy, instead run the command at 3, the app run the command immediately. Why?

Comment: You are setting the time in Calendar but you also need to set it to next day otherwise it will be 3am today, which is in the past and will cause the alarm to trigger immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an alarm is set to a passed date it will trigger immediately, if you don't want that you can create some logic to only start it today if the current time is before 3AM, something like this would work:

```
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (now.before(cal)) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    } 
    else {
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) +1);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);   
    }
```

We created another calendar to use as a reference to the current time, and check if we are before 3AM, if not then only call the alarm a day after.

Comment: Yes, the only way it doesn't is if the user deletes the app

Comment: Fine! There was a problem in the method that calls. Thank you for help me!!